# How to redirect root URL to another page URL of the website via .htacess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

How can I redirect the main domain URL to another page via the .htacess file?

I have used this code and it is not working fine,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?uniqayalifestyle\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://uniqayalifestyle.com/winter-offers/$1 [R,L]
```

This is my URL: `https://uniqayalifestyle.com/` 
And I want to redirect to here: `https://uniqayalifestyle.com/winter-offers/`

Comment: These rules are working fine for me. Could you please check once if your htaccess rules are really getting kicked off. Take a backup of your current htaccess file and then try placing `----------` kind of junk lines in it, then restart apache and see if you get 500 internal error, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 dear sir, it is not working, please let me know if there is any other solution, please.

Comment: sure, yeah I am trying to help, could you please do do things which I have requested in my previous comment?

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I would suggest that instead of repeating your question you actually listen to the advice you are offered.

Comment: @arkascha I have already mentioned earlier that the above suggestion or advice is not working on my side. So please help if you have any other best solution.

Comment: Sorry, but "it's not working" is not a valid answer to the question "and see if you get 500 internal error, let me know how it goes". What @RavinderSingh13 asked you to do is implement a definite syntax error into your configuration file to check whether it is interpreted _at all_ . You never answered to that.

Comment: @arkascha so as per your request no error is showing by the redirection and the main URL redirect to itself respectively. Hope you will understand and got my point in clear.
Because What I have mentioned earlier is not clearing your mindset.

Comment: Sorry again, but the question was not whether an error shows up when a request is done. But whether an error is thrown by your http server when you make a deliberate syntax error in your configuration file. That is the usual check to ensure that this file is considered and interpreted _at all_ ... Sorry if this is hard to understand for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using port `443` instead of `80` since you were using `https`?

Instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

It should be:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
```

You can also try on `VirtualHost` level.

Following works and will redirect `https://uniqayalifestyle.com/` to `https://uniqayalifestyle.com/winter-offers/`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule   "^/$"  "/winter-offers/"  [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

You can customize this further according to your needs.